# Get datetime offset from user selected date considering daylight saving time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the date from javascript vie a Datepicker. But when the user picks a date from the past (outside the daylight saving time, during winter time) I get a lose of 1 hour, making me lose 1 day because of the daylight time extra offset which is not being counted.
How to I get the offset for the user selected date taking the daylight time/winter time in account for the timezone?

`var DateValueWithOffset = value.AddMinutes(-DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.TotalMinutes);`

Comment: Use Add.Minutes instead of offset.

Comment: This might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you really want to achieve? Do you need the `DateValueWithOffset`, or do you need the date the user actually selected? Do you need the date part only, or including time? Which JS datepicker are you using? How is the selected date send to the backend?

Comment: If you purely want to deal with dates (rather than datetimes), take a look at NodaTime (and in particular `LocalDate`)

Comment: I use some DevExpress Datepicker. The date comes with ISO format to the backend "2019-11-02T23:00:00.000Z", so the date gets parsed as UTC date and time and it gets automatically the offset. But what is important is to get the DateTimeOffset offset of the user selected date with considering the winter time (not daylight saving) and adding automatically 60 minutes to it